# React Navigation get stack header height

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How do i get the height of the StackNavigator header programmatically?

I need to detect if component A's position is within component B when pan gesture (drag) on A is released. However, the position from `onPanResponderRelease`'s `gesture.moveY` is measured with respect to the entire screen, whereas the position returned from A's `onLayout`is measured with respect to the parent view. So i'd need to know the parent view's current height to reconcile the differences.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

**React navigation V6**

```js
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';
const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
```

**React navigation V5**

```js
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
```

or with [React Context's API](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertransparent) (not recommended)

**React navigation V4**

```js
import { Header } from 'react-navigation-stack';
const headerHeight = Header.HEIGHT;
```

**React navigation V2-V3**

```js
import { Header } from 'react-navigation';
const headerHeight = Header.HEIGHT;
```

---

[Another answer to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55152318/in-react-navigation-how-do-i-get-the-dimensions-of-the-visible-area-between-the)

Comment: This code is not working anymore: 
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2411

Comment: How do we do this in React Nav V5

Comment: In version 5, there is either `useHeaderHeight` hook, or `HeaderHeightContext` provided by `@react-navigation/stack`. You can find it on this page - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

Comment: Thank you for the v5 version. I'm using this with https://github.com/osdnk/react-native-reanimated-bottom-sheet

`snapPoints={[screenHeight - headerHeight, 200]}`

Comment: V5 solution gives me this error: `Error: Couldn't find the header height. Are you inside a screen in Stack?` or this: `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component...`.

Comment: The context solution returns `undefined` and the hook solution return the error as RobiZzT stated above. Truth be told this functionality is *really* poorly documented...

Comment: the value of `const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight()` is `0`!

Comment: What about class components? Or do you all assume everyone uses Hooks nowadays?

Comment: in v6, we need to download a different package for one simple thing (though it provides a lot of other functionalities but styles should have been included). Anyway, on android, header height is nearly 80 dp

Answer (score 8):

**For React navigation V6:**

you can use this for functional components

```
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';
```

and this for both class components and functional components

```
import { HeaderHeightContext } from '@react-navigation/elements';

// ...

<HeaderHeightContext.Consumer>
  {headerHeight => {
    /* render something and use "headerHeight" in child components*/
  }}
</HeaderHeightContext.Consumer>
```

[Read More from Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements/#headerheightcontext)

Comment: You are rendering a new component there, you are not getting the header height value! Please check what are you posting before you post

Answer (score 3):

These are the helpers that I use.
 **getHeaderHeight** method gets the correct height in every platform (including iphone x) and orientation:

```
import { Dimensions, DeviceInfo, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Header } from 'react-navigation';

export const LANDSCAPE = 'landscape';
export const PORTRAIT = 'portrait';

export const getHeaderHeight = () => {
  let height;
  const orientation = getOrientation();
  height = getHeaderSafeAreaHeight();
  height += DeviceInfo.isIPhoneX_deprecated && orientation === PORTRAIT ? 24 : 0;

  return height;
};

// This does not include the new bar area in the iPhone X, so I use this when I need a custom headerTitle component
export const getHeaderSafeAreaHeight = () => {
  const orientation = getOrientation();
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && orientation === LANDSCAPE && !Platform.isPad) {
    return 32;
  }
  return Header.HEIGHT;
};

export const getOrientation = () => {
  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
  return width > height ? LANDSCAPE : PORTRAIT;
};
```

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2411#issuecomment-382434542

Answer (score 0):

I use [`measureInWindow()`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation) for this.

It takes stack navigator height into account.

Comment: any example????

Comment: @dontdownvoteme, Please elaborate, example of what you need.

Comment: any example of how you have successfully used this, because I was not able to find something relevant.

Comment: I don't have an example at hand, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the official docs as of today:

```
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements';

// ...

const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
```

This is working well for me in my application.

[Link to the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/elements#useheaderheight)