# In react-navigation, how do I get the dimensions of the visible area between the header and TabBar?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

const viewableWindowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height  - Header.HEIGHT - ???

How do I get the TabBar height?
What if the iPhone is X? How can I take that into account?

Comment: you can use `SafeAreaView` instead so it will apply the padding  automatically especially for phones like iphoneX

Comment: This may be a good article to read. It should explain SafeAreView depending on your version: [SafeAreaView react-navigation to fix iPhone X design issue](https://medium.com/@maheshnandam/use-safeareaview-from-react-navigation-to-fix-iphone-x-design-issue-ba531a9181d)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Solution 1

If you want to calculate viewable window height directly, then you can use the onLayout callback, for eg, on tab navigation each page,

```
 render() {
      return (
     <View style={{ flex: 1}} onLayout={(event) => {
              var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
              this.viewableWindowHeight=height;
              // use height as viewableWindowHeight
       }} />

    <ScollView>
     //Your scrollable contant
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);
```

> Solution 2

According to an issue in react navigation, you can't directly calculate the height of the bottom tab Bar. But if you wrap bottom tab bar into a view and then you can calculate that views height as bottom tab bar. Consider the example below

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation';

class TabBarComponent extends Component {
  measure = () => {
    if (this.tabBar) {
      this.tabBar.measureInWindow(this.props.setTabMeasurement);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        ref={(el) => { this.tabBar = el; }}
        onLayout={this.measure}
      >
        <BottomTabBar {...this.props} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    setTabMeasurement: (x, y, width, height) => dispatch({
      type: 'SET_TAB_MEASUREMENT',
      measurement: {
        x, y, width, height,
      },
    }),
  };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TabBarComponent);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import { Dimensions, Platform } from 'react-native';
import {
  getStatusBarHeight,
  getBottomSpace,
} from 'react-native-iphone-x-helper';
import { Header } from 'react-navigation';

const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
  const stackHeaderHeight = Header.HEIGHT;

  /* Taken from source code of react-navigation-tabs*/
  const TAB_BAR_DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 49;
  const TAB_BAR_COMPACT_HEIGHT = 29;

  const TAB_BAR_HEIGHT = this.bottomTabBarRef._shouldUseHorizontalLabels() && !Platform.isPad
    ? TAB_BAR_COMPACT_HEIGHT
    : TAB_BAR_DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

  const marginTop = getStatusBarHeight() + stackHeaderHeight;
  const marginBottom = getBottomSpace() + TAB_BAR_HEIGHT;

  // < What you're after 
  const viewableWindowHight = height - marginTop - marginBottom;
```

**FOR TBBAR**

Height is changing between these two values >> `TAB_BAR_COMPACT_HEIGHT`, and `TAB_BAR_DEFAULT_HEIGHT`, according to a condition determined by this method:

According to [react-navigation-tabs](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs/blob/d2aa789109ed0df61c0c0ac7b759ac386a720804/src/views/BottomTabBar.js#L181) source code.

**OR**

You could set `initialLayout` to your `TabNavigatorConfig` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html):

> initialLayout - Optional object containing the initial height and
>   width, can be passed to prevent the one frame delay in
>   react-native-tab-view rendering.

**FOR IPHONE-X**

You can access statusBar height, bottomSpace in Iphone-X safely though [react-native-iphone-x-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iphone-x-helper) npm module

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [SafeAreaView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview) which will automatically set topBarHeight mainly for iPhoneX phones.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version use

`import { useHeaderHeight } from "react-navigation-stack";
 console.log(useHeaderHeight());`