# How do I get the header height for a React Navigation Native Stack with a large header?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-native-stack

Similar to [React Navigation get stack header height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734664/react-navigation-get-stack-header-height) but I am looking specifically at Native Stack with a large header.

`useHeaderHeight` from `import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/elements'` gives a fixed number and does not adjust depending on the state of the header.